Why does rsync not copy the other execute bit when copying to an sshfs mount?
I have a mounted sshfs drive at /mnt/backup_datascrape with permission rwxrwxr-x. I am trying to copy a directory foo with permission rwxrwxr-x to that mount using rsync while preserving the permissions. But when I do this, the permission for the copied directory on the sshfs mount is rwx------. If I change the permission for directory foo to rwxrwxr--, rsync correctly preserves the permissions. So in this situation it appears rsync removes all non user permissions if there is a global execute permission set. Does anyone know why this is? This is the command I use to rsync.
rsync -avhz --delete --exclude 'env' /home/datascrape/foo /mnt/backup_datascrape/

The copy will be more efficient if you have rsync talk directly to the remote server instead of reading/writing via the sshfs mount

I did learn that today in googling this answer and I'm switching over to the process. But I'm still curious why sshfs and rsync are acting the way they are. It seems odd.
